# Active Directory Certificate Service - How to list all the available certificate templates in the CA Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, certificate, x509certificate, ca

I have CA server set up in windows server. I have a client code in C# which created CSR sends to the server and downloads the issued certificate from the server. I want to know can retrieve a **list of certificate templates** which are there in CA server using **C#** code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of assigned to CA server templates can be retrieved by using [`ICertRequest2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/certcli/nn-certcli-icertrequest2) COM interface and calling the [`ICertRequest2::GetCAProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/certcli/nf-certcli-icertrequest2-getcaproperty) method.

You will have to add a `CertCli` COM library reference (in Visual Studio). Alternatively, you can create introp library by using `tlbimp.exe` tool from `certcli.dll` library and then use `CCertRequest` class which implements `ICertRequest` interface.

In order to retrieve the list of certificate templates, pass the `CR_PROP_TEMPLATES` value in `dwPropId` parameter. For more details about `GetCAProperty` method call you can consult with [`ICertRequestD2::GetCAProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc249749.aspx) DCOM description which is part of MS-WCCE protocol specification.

The method returns string value in the following format: `TemplateName1\nTemplateOID1\nTemplateName2\nTemplateOID2\...`. You can split this string with `\n` character into an array of strings, where each even (assuming zero-based index) element represents template display name (not common name, or `cn` attribute) and odd element represents template OID. More details about output: [[MS-WCCE] §3.2.2.6.3.1.1 PropID=0x0000001D (CR_PROP_TEMPLATES) "Configured Certificate Templates"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc249980.aspx)